# Express `req.body` is empty

Tags: post, express

I am trying to access some posted form data with and Express route. When my form is posted, the data should be handled by an `express.Router()` route. When I post however, my body contains `{}`. My code is as follows:

### Router

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('../views/index.jade');
}); 

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

### Form

```
form(id="task_form" action="/tasks" method="POST")
        input(type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Task name Here" name="task[task]" required)
        input(type="submit")
    div(class="tasks")
        - if(tasks != undefined)
            p #{tasks.task}
        - else
            p No tasks found
```

### main app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = require('./include/router');
var database = require('./include/database');

var app = module.exports = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/styles'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/img'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/tasks', router);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.send('404 not found', 404);
}); 

app.listen(80);
```

Why is my body empty? Do I need to change the `bodyParser`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the endpoint, because you are using

```
action="/tasks" method="POST"
```

and your endpoint is

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

it should be

```
router.post('**/tasks**', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

Are you seeing the differences?

I think that is the problem!

have fun!

Comment: No :(, I have tried changing the router's mount to '/' I also tried changing the POST url to '/', but no matter what happens touting acts up or I get an empty body.

Comment: Are you tried doing this whit a console.log(req)? what do you see on body or params? (req.body) (req.params) 

And what is "name="task[task]"" (I mean the double task)

Comment: both body and params are `{}`

Comment: I'm out of ideas :( we have to wait. Sry